# gnuplot: add extra keys

Tags: key, gnuplot, histogram, legend

I have a simple gnuplot script to plot a histogram with differently colored bars, with each color representing a group.

How can I show 3 different keys (1 red, 1 green and 1 blue)?

This is my script:

```
unset title 
set key left
set yrange [0:10]
set ylabel 'Score'
set xtics rotate out
set style histogram gap 1
set style data histogram
set style fill solid 1.00 border 0
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'red'
set linetype 2 lc rgb 'red'
set linetype 3 lc rgb 'red'
set linetype 4 lc rgb 'green'
set linetype 5 lc rgb 'green' 
set linetype 6 lc rgb 'green'
set linetype 7 lc rgb 'blue'
set linetype 8 lc rgb 'blue'
set linetype 9 lc rgb 'blue'
set xtics nomirror 
set ytics nomirror
plot 'example.dat' using ($0):2:($0+1):xtic(1) with boxes linecolor variable notitle
```

and here my example.dat file:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
F 6
G 7
H 8
I 9
```

I have not 10 rep points to post imgs, so these are imgur links to:
[what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWePI.jpg) and [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu5PN.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about defining all those styles by hand and work within a loop instead:

```
unset title 
set key left
set yrange [0:10]
set ylabel 'Score'
set xtics rotate out
set style histogram gap 1
set style data histogram
set style fill solid 1.00 border 0
set xtics nomirror 
set ytics nomirror
plot for [i=1:3] 'example.dat' \
every ::((i-1)*3)::((i-1)*3+2) using ($0+i*3):2:xtic(1) \
with boxes linecolor i title "Gpr".i
```

[image]

The code above loops from 1 to 3, each time plotting one of the groups. `every` selects the points to plot, and the title is obtained as a string concatenation. The line color is chosen simply as `i` from 1 to 3, but you could use a complicated conditional expression:

```
f(x)=(x == 1 ? "magenta" : x == 2 ? "yellow" : "cyan")
plot for [i=1:3] 'example.dat' \
every ::((i-1)*3)::((i-1)*3+2) using ($0+i*3):2:xtic(1) \
with boxes linecolor rgb f(i) title "Gpr".i
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Miguel, it's clever! But, is it possible to accomplish the same task avoiding the 'ever' loop and sticking with the color def as in my example ? Thanks again

Comment: You need to plot once per legend title, so you will need `every` even if you replace the loop by 3 explicit items in the plot command.